# ngtools/webpack ExtractI18nPlugin usage

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I have been trying to do localization with i18n through Webpack and Angular.

I came across the plugin in the cli tools of Angular https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/packages/%40ngtools/webpack/src/extract_i18n_plugin.ts

But i have not gotten it to work, anybody knows how to set it up?

I just get the usual "Error: Can't resolve '../aot/src/app/app.module.ngfactory'", but purely running aot, works fine.

```
var helpers = require('./helpers');
var ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
var AotPlugin = ngtools.AotPlugin;
var ExtractI18nPlugin = ngtools.ExtractI18nPlugin

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'polyfills': './src/polyfills.ts',
        'vendor': './src/vendor-aot.ts',
        'app': './src/main-aot.ts'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                use: ['@ngtools/webpack']
            }
        ]
    },

    plugins: [
        new ExtractI18nPlugin({
            outFile: "src/i18n",
            tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig-aot.json')
        }),
        new AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: helpers.root('tsconfig-aot.json'),
            entryModule: helpers.root('src/app/app.module#AppModule')
        })

    ]
};
```

Comment: Take a look at this issue thread:
https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/3163

This is something that is not really fully supported yet when it concerns an **ejected** Angular project, OOTB. I'm in the process of implementing this myself, but maybe the thread helps you on your way!

Answer (score 0):

I did see a note elsewhere that you need to put the ExtractI18nPlugin after the AotPlugin, like so:

```
"plugins": [
// ...
new AotPlugin({
   "mainPath": "main.ts",
   "i18nFile": "src/i18n/messages.fr.xlf",
   "i18nFormat": "xlf",
   "locale": "fr",
   "replaceExport": false,
   "missingTranslation": "error",
   "hostReplacementPaths": {
   "environments\\environment.ts": "environments\\environment.ts"
},
"exclude": [],
"tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json"
}),
new ExtractI18nPlugin({
   "tsConfigPath": "src\\tsconfig.app.json",
   "exclude": [],
   "i18nFormat": "xlf",
   "locale": "fr",
   "outFile": "i18n/test.xlf",
}) 
// ... 
]
```

Comment: the important part is to add the ExtractI18nPlugin at the end of your plugins list